# How to add confirmation yes or no in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add yes/no confirmation before I submit? I want to have alert message before I proceed to remove or edit. How to do that?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('a.button.edit, a.button.remove').click(function () {
            if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            var frm = document.myform;
                if($(this).hasClass('edit')){
                frm.action = 'editpr.php';
            }
                if($(this).hasClass('remove')){
            }
            frm.submit();
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) to display a confirmation dialog.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.button.edit, a.button.remove').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if(!confirm('do you want to contine')){
            return
        }

        var frm = document.myform;
        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            frm.action = 'editpr.php';
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {}
        frm.submit();
    })
})
```

Comment: this my new question, please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183466/open-page-in-modal-box/20183499?noredirect=1#20183499